# Which platform is ideal for performance?

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning, memory

I have been using `NDSolve`, and I noticed that when you decrease the `MaxStepSize`, possible singularities are resolved.

If I decrease the step size past a certain point (less than `0.01`), Wolfram Engine terminates because the peak system memory limit was reached.

Will a good computer + *Mathematica* do much better than a chromebook + *Mathematica Online*?

```
A = 1.4; B =20;
sol = NDSolve[{ D[v1[x, t], t] + 1/2 D[v1[x, t]^2, x] == (A )*v2[x, t] -  B v1[x, t],
D[v2[x, t], t] + 1/2 D[v2[x, t]^2, x] == (A)*v1[x, t] - B v2[x, t],
v1[x, 0] == 2, v2[x,0]==40, v2[0, t] == 40, v1[0,t] ==2, v2[10,t]==40},
{v1, v2}, {x, 0, 10}, {t, 0, 20}, MaxStepSize -> 0.001];
```

Comment: …you might want to consider posting the differential equation that is giving you trouble.

Comment: In general, the maximum amount of memory for a cloud session is limited (0.5, 1 or 2 GB depending on the plan). If you need to use more, a computer with an appropriate amount of RAM will likely do better.

Answer (score 1):

> In general, the maximum amount of memory for a cloud session is limited (0.5, 1 or 2 GB depending on the plan). If you need to use more, a computer with an appropriate amount of RAM will likely do better.
>
> – ilian Jun 6 at 5:39